# How to prevent Intellij from showing me the org.testng.TestNGException (Test framework quit unexpectedly)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, ant, testng

I'm having the exception below when trying to run tests individually in intellij.
The tests I'm trying to run are written in a project built with Ant. The Ant target that runs all unit tests from the projects runs successfully, with no exception.
The exception appears when I try to run a class of tests or a test individually.

```
*org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot find class in classpath: com.project.test.Test
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.loadClass(XmlClass.java:74)*
```

Is there a way to configure intellij so that it is able to access the build directory and find the jars it needs? I'm using the latest version of Intellij.

Update: I fixed this by changing the Compiler in intellij from javac to eclipse. I assume this fixed everything because the project I wanted to run tests for was made of many modules written in eclipse.

Comment: what are your Run Config settings for all tests and for individual ones? can you maybe share a link to your repo so it would also be clear how your project and tests are organised?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't share a screenshot of the configuration from Intellij, but I can tell that the use classpath of module the  it's the module that test belongs to, the jre is the one I have on my PATH and I configured an output folder for the tests. I tried running the Ant build before the test (using the Before Launch tab from intellij available when I edit the Run configuration, but the exception is the same). Here is a list of the options I have when opening the run config: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-testng.html#codeCoverageTab if you might have a suggestion

Comment: btw, which version of IDEA do you use, and do you have plugin "Ant Build Generation" installed?

Comment: the latest version, I'm using Mac OS, and I do not have the "Ant Build Generation" installed. I just added my build.xml in the Ant view from intellj.

Comment: I realised that if I have the application open in Eclipse, with the Build Automatically option checked, I'm able to run a class of tests successfully in Intellij. My assumption is that IntelliJ cannot build the application by itself, even though the Ant build is successful

Answer (score 0):

Usually in Eclipse, we need to add TestNG library (just like jre/jdk) in classpath/buildpath to run classes. So try same.

[image]

Comment: I tried adding the testng jar in Project Structure -> Modules from Intellij and it changed nothing. :(

Comment: you need to add as library